# How to save layout as an image with scroll view?

Tags: android, android-layout

My UI is something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout...>
  <ScrollView .../>
   ...
</LinearLayout...>
```

I can save the whole LinearLayout as a bitmap.
But once I use scrollbar, the output is not
the "completed" image as I expected.

Would you please give me some hint?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is mean by "output is not the "completed" image as I expected" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205769/taking-screenshot-of-activity-programatically. check this if ithelps

Answer (score 2):

Make ScrollView as parent...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
 >
Your other content
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```